# Installing environment descriptions in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, build, environment

I have `Execution environment references were not checked for '...' because no environment descriptions are installed.` error.

[image]

I guess I need to install environment descriptions (http://wiki.eclipse.org/Execution_Environment_Descriptions) for the org.eclipse.jdt.core project that causes this error.

How can I install environment descriptions in eclipse?

Comment: What version of Eclipse is this?

Comment: It's Eclipse for RCP and RAP Developers Version: Juno Service Release 1.

Comment: Which was released in September, and that bug was closed in June. Sigh. Can't help you :-/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I got an answer from this site - http://wiki.eclipse.org/Execution_Environments#Installing_Execution_Environment_Descriptions

In short, you can install software for Execution Environment Descriptor.

[image]
[image]

to remove the error.

[image]

Comment: worth to note that currently the download URL is http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.3 and that a Clean is required after installing the Execution Environment Descriptor